# Betting and Search for uniqueness

Tags: java

I've been working ahead in my intro class and I've almost finished my last project, Keno. its a betting game that rewards money according to how many numbers you matched with the dealer. I'm having issues on where to put the betting aspect, they start with 100$ and are asked to wage a certain amount of money.  I don't know which method that would go under for it to still work because my methods aren't voids, so i wont be able to return more than one data value.

My second issue, maybe the more important one, is that they need to be unique numbers. To do that i would need to search the array of numbers every time to see if they match, or use an array of booleans to keep track of the numbers. I don't know how i would do the second but i have a good idea of what i would do with the first. The issue is that im using a do while already, im not sure how i could add the for loop with a nested for loop in. Here is my code, sorry if its messy, i know my teacher hates my curly braces:

```
package Keno;

import cs1.Keyboard;

public class Keno {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int userArr[]=user();
        int compArr[]=computer();
        int howMany=matchNums(compArr,userArr);
        int moneyGained=betting(howMany);

        System.out.println("You matched "+howMany+" numbers");
        System.out.println("You have gained "+moneyGained+" dollars!");

    }

    public static int[] computer(){
        int []compChoice=new int[20];
        for(int x=0;x<compChoice.length;x++){
            compChoice[x]=(int)(Math.random()*81);
        }
        return compChoice;
    }
    public static int[] user(){
        int choice[]=new int[7];
        System.out.println("Welcome to Keno!");
        System.out.println("Choose 7 unique numbers ranging from 1-80");
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
        //assigns numbers to choice array
        for(int x=0;x<choice.length;x++){
            do{
                int temp=x+1;
                System.out.println("number "+temp+": ");
                choice[x]=Keyboard.readInt();
            }while(choice[x]<0||choice[x]>80);

        }
        System.out.println("Thanks!");
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
        return choice;

    }
    public static int matchNums(int arr1[], int arr2[]){
        int count=0;
        //checks each array slot individually to see if they match
        for(int x=0;x<arr1.length;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<arr2.length;y++){
                if(arr1[x]==arr2[y]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static int betting(int matches){
        int moneyGained=0;
        if(matches==7){
            moneyGained=12000;
        }else if(matches==6){
            moneyGained=200;
        }else if(matches==5){
            moneyGained=20;
        }else if(moneyGained==4){
            moneyGained=1;
        }
        return moneyGained;
    }

}
```

Comment: For the first problem, what about creating a variable that would keep track of your current money and writing a method that returns the amount of money the user has decided to wage? (Which could then be used to update your initial variable)

Comment: Or use an arraylist and check .contains(number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to add the betting/money concept would be to add an integer which represents how much money the player has (starting at 100).  You will have to ask the player how much they want to wager, and then adjust their money accordingly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int playerMoney = 100;
  int wagered = getWager(); // dont forget it has to be 0 < wagered <= 100
  // adjust players money according to the wager, and how much they won
```

For ensuring uniqueness, either one of your ideas would work.  I like just checking for the numbers existence already in the array, but the boolean array of size 80 would work too.  It just seems like a lot for only 7 numbers though.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i'll definitely do that. I wasnt sure how i would add the method and have it work without clashing, but im good now.